# Calling ReactNative FlatList data from Firestore - Unable to do it

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flatlist

I am able to hardcode a FlatList that pulls information from a randomuser.org dataset. However, I'm totally unable to pull any data from my Firestore database - it just displays a blank page in Expo without any error warnings. I've been stuck on this for a few days and the more I search around the more confused I seem to be! I'm new to coding so I apologise if this is a really basic question. I've kept the picture of my code simple with just the FlatList in the App.js file - but as soon as I try to return data from Firestore it is just blank, no matter what I seem to do. Thank you

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKQTv.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpb9B.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I never seen any tries to fetch anything from Firebase Console UI. If you are following any tutorial please add the link to it.

Anyway, if I understand that you want to use `fetch` to get data. Not sure if this is possible with it, for sure not using url `http://firebase.google.com/project/project-name/firestore/data` as this is link to Firestore GUI and you will not be able to get anything useful from that.

If you want to get data from Firestore you have to use [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). The [simplest read example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#read_data) can be found in the documentation. So you have to use your database structure (means collections and documents) and create reference to what you want to pull. Than use some method like `get()`. I suggest to get familiar with whole API [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js).

Finally if you want to use it in react you have to integrate the API with your app. For this there is tones of nice articles about it. I think [this one](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/consume-data-from-firebase-firestore-in-a-react-app) is nice to start with.